# npm install is giving us a Dependency Tree Error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, node-modules, react-typescript

i made a commit to a repo today and when we tried to start the server it gave an error from react.script named "Type Error: chalk.constructor is not a constructor" as a fix we tried to delete lock files (we had both yarn and npm lock) and delete node modules files, and after an npm install after that, it gave us this error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-scripts@3.4.1
npm ERR! Found: typescript@4.0.8
npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
npm ERR!   typescript@"~4.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peerOptional typescript@"^3.2.1" from react-scripts@3.4.1  
npm ERR! node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: typescript@3.9.10
npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
npm ERR!   peerOptional typescript@"^3.2.1" from react-scripts@3.4.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!     react-scripts@"3.4.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.      
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See *** for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     ***
PS *** npm install   
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-scripts@3.4.1
npm ERR! Found: typescript@4.0.8
npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
npm ERR!   typescript@"~4.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peerOptional typescript@"^3.2.1" from react-scripts@3.4.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!   react-scripts@"3.4.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: typescript@3.9.10
npm ERR!   peerOptional typescript@"^3.2.1" from react-scripts@3.4.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!     react-scripts@"3.4.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.      
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See *** for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! ***
```

I censored the paths for privacy purposes. But after that i changed typescript package version to typescript@"^3.2.1" and it still didn't work, after that i used the "npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps" command and it still didn't work. Can anyone please offer any advice?

Update: The package.json is below

```
{
  "name": "company-name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.56",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.10.0",
    "@react-pdf/renderer": "2.0.0-beta.6",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-react": "^3.6.1",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/html2canvas": "^0.0.35",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.0",
    "@types/jspdf": "^1.3.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-color": "^3.0.4",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-notifications-component": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.9",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.5",
    "@types/react-text-mask": "^5.4.6",
    "@types/react-virtualized": "^9.21.10",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.0",
    "@types/yup": "^0.29.3",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "computed-style-to-inline-style": "^3.0.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fontsource-roboto": "3.0.3",
    "formik": "^2.1.5",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "html-to-image": "^1.6.1",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.7",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "js-file-download": "^0.4.12",
    "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "potrace": "^2.1.6",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap-sweetalert": "^5.2.0",
    "react-color": "^2.18.1",
    "react-credit-card-input": "^1.1.5",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-material-ui-carousel": "^2.0.0",
    "react-notifications-component": "^2.4.0",
    "react-player": "^2.4.0",
    "react-recaptcha": "^2.3.10",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.9",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-hash-link": "^2.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "react-text-mask": "^5.4.3",
    "react-virtualized": "^9.22.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2",
    "uuid": "^8.3.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.17.0",
    "yup": "^0.29.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "prod": "serve -s build -l 3000",
    "build-run-prod": "react-scripts build && serve -s build -l 3000"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I would try to set all dependencies in the package.json file to what you want.  then i would delete the package.lock.json and the node_modules folder completely and then try again

Comment: I currently changed "react-scripts": "3.4.1" line to "react-scripts": "^3.4.1" and deleting node_modules folder, and then i will delete all the lock files again and install, i'll make an update on what happened.

Comment: Unfortunately, that also did not work.

Comment: ok if you are working with yarn... you need to stick to yarn... if you are working with npm stick to npm... you should not have two lock files.   i would try to delete BOTH lock files and the node_modules folder then try yarn install.   I have been down this road before.  yarn and npm are NOT compatible.

Comment: if you love spending your life chasing down dependency resolution problems then use both npm and yarn in the same project.... if you want your project to work use only one of them.  i would try yarn just because npm is not working

Comment: The problem is, i already did that. Deleted both of them and the node_modules. Tried with npm, then deleted both again, tried with yarn, does not work at all,

Comment: i think at this point we need to see the complete package.json

Comment: I am linking the package.json file right now

Comment: I added the package.json file for more information, you can ask for anything else